# Why is nullifying a function prohibited in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Consider:

```
function a() { a = null; }
```

Why can't a be assigned?

Comment: Because the function has to be created before it can be destroyed, and once it's destroyed, it's no longer created, so it cannot execute anymore.  To put it another way, a snake can't eat it's own tail.

Comment: function in itself is an object.

Comment: Hm, there is not a single thing that would make it a problem in JavaScript moreover using a variable with a function expression isn't a problem either: `var a = function() { a = null; }`

Comment: What would be a practical use case for this?  Are you trying to write a `DestroyUniverse()` function?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I am helping GC to collect the junk promptly.

Comment: Ah, see there's probably a much better way to do that.  Ask us how to do that (be specific), instead of trying to come up with your own solution and asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Can't see why a question I asked I can't be addressed regardlessly of my way of doing things.

Comment: See [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that's unrelated. I wasn't looking for a `solution` in the first place, because I didn't have a `problem`. I just made an observation about TypeScript by accident and my curiosity was the only reason why I came here. If asking questions unbound to specific problems is a crime, then I beg your pardon.

Answer (score 4):

The spec seems quite restrictive here, but then function definitions behave quite strangely, so it is understandable. (That is, you can call them earlier in the source code than they are declared... strange!)

Only reference expressions can be assigned to, which are defined in [Section 4 of the spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) as:

> ... references are combinations of identifiers (section 4.3), parentheses (section 4.7), and  property accesses (section 4.10).

and in 4.3,

> An identifier expression that references a variable or parameter is classified as a reference. An identifier expression that references any other kind of entity is classified as a value (and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment).

So, you could change it from a function definition into a variable declaration, probably with little change to the rest of your code:

```
var foo = function() {
    foo = null;
}
```

Comment: There you go 10k. Congrats.. :)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript disallows assignment to declared functions because, as you've seen in the comments, it's a very rare thing to do intentionally. It's much more likely that you had a typo (you meant to assign to `aa` instead of `a`) than that you actually wanted to overwrite a declared function.